# Google maps getPlace().geometry always undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have autocomplete working great, i have included the library geometry,

```
<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry&key=xxaSyxxxxxxxx9xx&callback=initAutocomplete"></script>
```

Here is the html+js :

```
<input class="forminput" id="autocomplete" maxlength="30" type=text placeholder="Ex: street.."></input>  

let placeSearch;
let autocomplete;
const componentForm = {
  street_number: "short_name",
  route: "long_name",
  locality: "long_name",
  administrative_area_level_1: "short_name",
  country: "long_name",
  postal_code: "short_name",
};


function initAutocomplete() {

  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    document.getElementById("autocomplete"),
    { types: ["geocode"] }
  );
  //address only
  autocomplete.setFields(["address_component"]);
  //populate
  autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", fillInAddress);
}
```

When i read the results, places has no `geometry` property :

```
function fillInAddress() {

  const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  console.log(place); // is good
  console.log(place.geometry); // is undefined all the time

  for (const component of place.address_components) {
  const addressType = component.types[0];
  const val = component[componentForm[addressType]];
   alert(addressType + " " + val);   //  ****** this is good !!!
  }
```

How to get the geometry to work? i need the lat/log .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: The scope of autocomplete is just fine, i get the rest of the properties and you can understand that from my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who struggle, it was pretty simple,

```
  autocomplete.setFields(["address_component","geometry"]);
```

For some reason Google's docs almost hide it in their tutorial, but you must add it **ALSO** here to make it work.

This works also without including the `geometry` library.

Comment: The geometry library has nothing to do with the geometry object returned along with a place.